# Unity3D and the iPhonekeyboard?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to figure out how to use the iPhoneKeyboard function in Unity3D. I want to be able to run a function when a user hits the button "OK" in the keyboard. I just simply can't figure this out.

The second question in this matter is how I can change the "OK" to "Search"?

Answer (score 0):

check out [IPhoneKeyboard.Open](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/iPhoneKeyboard.Open.html) in the Reference.. there is one example

After you can process the user input using the [IPhoneKeybard.done](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/iPhoneKeyboard-done.html) attribute (also one example)